# .htaccess - Dois sites, domínios diferentes na mesma hospedagem

Tags: htaccess, domínio

Pessoal to com uma dúvida, gostaria de saber se é possível redirecionar um domínio para uma subpasta de uma hospedagem com um site sem alterar a URL do navegador via .htaccess.

Exemplo:
dominio1 - Hospedagem1
dominio2 - Hospedagem1/dominio2

é possível?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, sim é possível.
Vc coloca as regras dentro de site-available.
Coloca um Alias para fazer o redirecionamento para a segunda pasta.
Ex.:

```
https://www.example.com

https://www.example.com/blog
```